# How do i retrieve IFormFile from API and display it in view? i want the image(s) to be displayed in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, c#-7.0

how do i successfully retrieve IFormFile from the server side API and display it in my view image source. I was wondering why what i did never worked until i realize that i was using the path i saved in returned JSON thinking it to be same as in mvc web. Please help me in retrieving IFormFile .. i can successfully save the file in the file system in server which i can see the files in the folder and then correct path but not the file so that is my issue now. the way i was going with was just retrieving the path of the file in the API.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    List<Room> kd = new List<Room>();
    var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:7186/api/" + "Rooms");
    var requset = new RestRequest();
    var response = client.Get(requset);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        kd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Room>>(response.Content.ToString());
    }
    var ListRooms = kd.ToList();
return View(ListRooms);
}
```

in my model i have some properties together with IFormFIle so its actually to retrieve both properties and IFormFile. with this method i can get only the path to the file and other properties.

Comment: Hi @Alva Mira, so firstly does your deserialization of `List<Room>` work fine? Just for confirmation, it contains type of `IFormFile` property in your Room model, and you want to display this property as image, right?

Comment: @Rena yes. but my exact code does not givme me that from the API. thats what i needed; the IFormFile

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how is your api like, but for how to create the model with IFormFile property when the path is known, you could check the following code to create a IFormFile:

```
List<Room> model = new List<Room>();
string filePath = "path_to_your_file/image.png";

using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    // Create a FormFile object
    var file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null, Path.GetFileName(filePath))
    {
        Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
        ContentType = "application/octet-stream" 
    };
    model.Add(new Room(){ImgProperty=file });//other property add by yourself...
}
return model;
```

After the deserialization working fine, then you can create an extension method to convert `IFormFile` to base64 string to display the `IFormFile` as image:

```
namespace MvcProj.Extension
{
    public static class FormFileExtensions
    {
        public static string ToBase64String(this IFormFile formFile)
        {
            if (formFile == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(formFile));
            }

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                formFile.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the Index view:

```
@using MvcProj.Extension;
@model List<Room>

@if(Model!=null)
{
    foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        string base64tostring = FormFileExtensions.ToBase64String(item.ImgFile);//replace with your IFormFile property
        var Imagesrc = string.Format("data:Image/*;base64," + base64tostring);
        <img src="@Imagesrc" />
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hi @AlvaMira, if so,  You need edit your question and share how is your api like. Also, pls set breakpoint to the api and check if it returns correct model with IFormFile.

Comment: Hi @AlvaMira, updated my answer. pls check.